# Load a different image in Outlook HTML

Tags: html, outlook, gif

Im creating an email template with a gif, but gifs animations doesnt work in Outlook. I know that Outlook loads the first frame of the gif, but in my case, this first frame is a white frame.

Is anyway to load other image (a jpg image for example) ONLY in Outlook???

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please vist the [help] and take the [tour] to see what and how to ask. HINT: Post code and effort. That said, this might be a question for superuser rather than here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gif normally are blocked by mail services.
If you create an HTML template you can put a .jpg or .png without problems.
You can also put an image without problems although it can be blocked.